# Return X weeks high in pine-script

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

To get the 52-week high of closing price, I use the following code in tradingview;

```
High52 = ta.highest(close, 52)
```

I would like to do the reverse and find out the X-week high of the **mouse-selected** close price.

How do I find X?

I want to find out whether the **mouse-selected** close price is a 52-week high or a 40-week high or a 20-week high. This is what I mean by X-week high.

This is the definition of 52-week high.

[https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/52weekhighlow.asp#:~:text=What%20Is%2052%2DWeek%20High,that%20equates%20to%20one%20year](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/52weekhighlow.asp#:%7E:text=What%20Is%2052%2DWeek%20High,that%20equates%20to%20one%20year).

I am using pine-script v5

Comment: What do you mean with 52-week high? Like the high for each 52 weeks? Or the high 52 weeks ago?

Comment: @Allart, highest close price for past 52 weeks.

Comment: Would this work: `ta.highest(close)` or `ta.highest(close[0], 52)`? Or try 1 or 2 in the array.

Comment: What you're asking is not very clear. You want a number of weeks from today to the all-time highest close price, is that it? Else what does you mean by "X-week high of the most recent close price" exactly, can you give an example?

Comment: @evilmandarine, I want to find out whether the latest close price is a 52-week high or a 40-week high or a 20-week high. This is what I mean by X-week high.

Comment: @Allart,  this link explains definition of 52week high https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/52weekhighlow.asp#:~:text=What%20Is%2052%2DWeek%20High,that%20equates%20to%20one%20year

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what the result should be if the time frame is not 1 week, because in this case x-week high does not have a meaning. For example for a 1 day time frame, latest close could be higher than one week before, or 2 or more weeks, but in between daily closes could be higher than latest close.
Here's a solution that works if you set the time frame to 1 week ("W") in the main graph. There is an offset parameter that allows to shift the starting point to demonstrate that it works for any point. A loop is required, because as per the documentation:

> Looking back in history to analyze bars using a reference value that
> can only be known on the current bar, e.g., to find how many past
> highs are higher than the high of the current bar. Since the current
> bar’s high is only known on the bar the script is running on, a loop
> is necessary to go back in time and analyze past bars.

**Script:**

```javascript
//@version=5
indicator("x-week high", overlay = true)

startOffsetInBars = 0
i         = startOffsetInBars + 1
last      = close[startOffsetInBars]
lastClose = close[i]

if barstate.islast
    while last > lastClose
        i += 1
        lastClose := close[i]

    // days * 10, weeks * 7
    weeks = (time_close[startOffsetInBars] - time_close[i - 1])/((360000 * 24) * 10 * 7)

    lbl1 = label.new(
         x=bar_index[startOffsetInBars],
         y=close[startOffsetInBars],
         text=str.tostring(str.tostring(weeks) + "-week high"),
         textcolor=color.black,
         style=label.style_label_upper_left,
         size=size.small,
         color=color.lime)

    lbl2 = label.new(
         x=bar_index[i], 
         y=close[i],
         text=str.tostring("higher"),
         textcolor=color.black,
         style=label.style_label_upper_left,
         size=size.small,
         color=color.orange)
```

**Results:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not that familiar with pinescript but I think this might help you in the right direction:

```js
highest = 0
highest_week = 0

// Loop trough each 52 weeks. Not sure if starting at 0 will work. Switch it to 1 to 53 if not.
for offset = 0 to 52

    // Check if the close value of X week is higher then the highest found so far (starting at 0). 
    // If so, set a new highest value and highest week value, to remember which week was the highest.
    // You should use `highest_week := offset + 1` if you dont want week numbers to start at 0.
    if ta.highest(close, offset) > highest
        highest := ta.highest(close, offset)
        highest_week := offset

// After this for loop, highest_week should be the highest week found.
```

I'd say you change it to the point you would need it. I think with this example you can do it but then again, I have limited knowledge in this. If this ain't it then idk.